# How to remove unexpected white space above "page-break-before: always" CSS

Tags: html, css, page-break-before

For reproducible example, see this link - `https://cbbanalytics.com/stats/27694/games/1864019/overview`. On this page, we have added (via the class `print-break`) a `page-break-before: always` CSS to the `<h3>` element with the Stanford logo and text `Stanford Team Shot Charts`, as shown below. The goal is to create a neat PDF on print or save.

[image]

.
.
.

When printing this page or saving to PDF, while the page-break seems to work, there is an added white space at the top of the 2nd page above this `<h3>` element, the source of which we are not sure...:

[image]

.
.
.

When we force print preview mode following the [instructions here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/print-preview/), there is no such white space shown in the browser above the header / below the tables above.

[image]

.
.
.
Note that the empty div with `margin-top: 60px` just above the `<h3`> element is hidden on print (via the `hide-print` class which adds `display: none` to the `div` for print, and deleting this `div` **does not** fix the issue of the white space atop the page-break. What else could possibly be causing this white-space issue? It is entirely messing up how this page looks when printed or saved to PDF.

**EDIT:** when we delete the element with class=`controller-navbar-container`, (the red bar on top with the team names & logos), the page-break issue is fixed. So perhaps this is the root of the issue. However, we have no idea why this causes / fixes the page-break issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "hide-print row" div and under the elemenet ("hide-print row") on "row" add margin-top:40px.

Comment: This does not remove the problematic white space at the top of the 2nd page on print preview - in fact it makes that white space even larger!

Answer (score 0):

Use the media print to hide the element that is adding the space which is `hide-print` class.

```
@media print{
   .hide-print{
       display:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the recommendation, but we are already doing this! This is part of what it so confusing with this problem. It is NOT the `hide-print` class that is adding the problematic white space on print, as mentioned in the question! We have tried removing this div entirely and it has not helped with the issue.

Comment: You can see yourself by entirely deleting that div - the problematic white space is still on top of the page break.